# Access a Google Doc via API with a shared URL (AuthKey)?

Tags: curl, google-docs, google-docs-api

Google Docs allows you to share a document with just the URL.  The URL contains a key and authkey to identify the document and authorize access.  This allows anonymous access to anyone who has the key.

I would like to access this type of shared document within an application.  I've looked at the APIs, and haven't seen anything yet.  It seems like this should be possible - since you can access such a document anonymously with a browser, why shouldn't an application be able to access the same document?  Anyone know if/how this can be done?

Comment: They've recently added the 'authkey' older spreadsheets dont have them. I now have the same problem. QL reference http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/querylanguage.html

Comment: If you provide an example of the way you're using a non-AuthKey Doc in your application, that would narrow down this question significantly.

Answer (score 4):

Update for anyone who lands here in 2017+ (as I did). Google seems to have changed the way that share links look. They now look like this when you click get shareable link.

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[idwillbehere]/edit#gid=0`

You can download the the spreadsheet with this curl command. Make sure the sheet is set so that anyone with the link can access it.

`curl -o /path/to/file/you/want/csv/to/go.csv 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=[the-id-of-your-spreadsheet]&output=csv' -L`

the `-L` is the trick here has google often moves the csv around but will send you a redirect link. `-L` tells `curl` to follow the redirects until it lands on the file.

Comment: I really wish there was a convenient way of also using that token for allowing per-file access to other applications, especially to enable writing.  Does anyone know if that's a "thing"?

Answer (score 2):

Some info may help:

When sharing a doc with the link, the URL look like:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxx/edit?hl=en&authkey=yyyyy

To get a copy of the document from curl/wget, use the URL like
https://docs.google.com/document/d/xxxxx/export?hl=en&authkey=yyyyy&exportFormat=pdf

See http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDocs for Exporting document.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, excellent advice, I got the URL from the Google Docs API. This is now supplanted by the Google Drive API at https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple URL to access the document, in this format:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/<type>/Export?docID=<document_ID>&exportFormat=<format>
```

Type could be any of these
 - documents
 - spreadsheets
 - drawings
 - presentations

Format could be any of these

- html
- txt
- rtf
- doc
- odt
- xls
- ods
- jpeg
- png
- svg
- ppt

For more details, please refer to the `Google Drive API` at https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

Here is an example of a URL to export a Google Presentation as PDF

https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export?docID=15HI6KUtc7dm1jZuk1JY022wxWMcYzz3CiC0dxokokak&exportFormat=pdf

Comment: Looks like they may have changed this. Your example doesn't work, and neither does the example I tried.

Comment: This (almost) works for me. However, the URL before the question mark should end in '/export'  (lower case 'e'), not ' Export'.